# scrapy HtmlXPathSelector determine xpath by searching for keyword

Tags: xpath, lxml, scrapy

I have a portion of html like below

```
<li><label>The Keyword:</label><span><a href="../../..">The text</a></span></li>
```

I want to get the string "The keyword: The text".

I know that I can get xpath of above html using Chrome inspect or FF firebug, then hxs.select(xpath).extract(), then strip html tags to get the string. However, the approach is not generic enough since the xpath is not consistent across different pages.

Hence, I'm thinking of below approach:
Firstly, search for "The Keyword:" using

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
hxs.select('//*[contains(text(), "The Keyword:")]')
```

When do pprint I get some return:

```
>>> pprint( hxs.select('//*[contains(text(), "The Keyword:")]') )
<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//*[contains(text(), "The Keyword:")]' data=u'<label>The Keyword:</label>'>
```

My question is how to get the wanted string: "The keyword: The text". I am thinking of how to determine xpath, if xpath is known, then of course I can get the wanted string.

I am open to any solution other than scrapy HtmlXPathSelector. ( e.g lxml.html might have more features but I am very new to it).

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [lxml.html extract a string by searching for a keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004623/lxml-html-extract-a-string-by-searching-for-a-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, "following-sibling" is what you are looking after.

```
 //*[contains(text(), "The Keyword:")]/following-sibling::span/a/text()
```

[Xpath Axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp)